# Identify this book about a group of people that get stuck inside a cave and develop a community inside it

Tags: story-identification

I read this book at least 30 years ago, so I really don't remember almost anything and I believe this is my best chance to find this book.

It was like a school vacation to the forest and with a cave exploration but something happens and they get stuck inside the cave, their teacher gets injured and cannot move so he is just observing and telling what the teenagers are doing. The only detail I remember was that due to the humidity (?) inside the cave they start talking like with a stuffy nose and invent new words and rules, I don't remember if they find a way out in the end or not.